using pure javascript and css, how to scroll a list of clickable divs on a touchscreen?
This is a local page that runs on an Android tablet.
That tablet will be not connected to any network, so everything needs to stay in the device storage.
HTML code:
    <div class="container">
        <div class="half" id="ListaCanzoni">
            <p class="song-name" id="1">Titolo 1</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="2">Titolo 2</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="3">Titolo 3</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="4">Titolo 4</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="5">Titolo 5</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="6">Titolo 6</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="7">Titolo 7</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="8">Titolo 8</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="9">Titolo 9</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="10">Titolo 10</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="11">Titolo 11</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="12">Titolo 12</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="13">Titolo 13</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="14">Titolo 14</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="15">Titolo 15</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="16">Titolo 16</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="17">Titolo 17</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="18">Titolo 18</p>
            <p class="song-name" id="19">Titolo 19</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rendering-target half" id="song"></div>
    </div>

CSS code:
body  {
    overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #002;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container
{
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.half
{
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.song-name {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
    padding: 0px 36px 0px 16px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    user-select: none;
}

#ListaCanzoni {
  background-color: #024;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  height: 90vh;
}
#ListaCanzoni::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


.title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
  color: #0FF;
  background-color: #042;
}

javascript code:
const songDiv = document.getElementById('song');
const item = document.querySelectorAll(".song-name");
item.forEach(function (el) {
  el.onclick = function () {
    songDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="title">' + this.id + '</div>';
    console.log (this.id);
    console.log (songDiv.innerHTML);
  }
});

The page is also in this JSFiddle .
The left half contains a list of clickable buttons (divs) and i'd like to hide any scrollbar but let the user be able to scroll it with the usual "drag" action on the touch screen.
How could i allow this action without generating clicks?
I'd like a solution which does not requires any additional js libraries/plugins, but if not possible at least one which requires the minimum possible.
EDIT
updated code and fiddle with the container height as suggested by A Aworth

I can’t see where you have given a height (or max-height) to the container.

I didn't. And i see that now that i've done it in the JSFiddle it scrolls with the mousewheel, so i missed that part for sure.

There's no need for you to try and manipulate the scrollbar on your #ListaCanzoni since it doesn't have a scrollbar. And because you set overflow: hidden; on your body, you're unable to scroll at all.
Instead you could try the following:
:root::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
:root {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

body  {
  background-color: #002;
}

The ::-webkit-scrollbar is used for WebKit-based browsers, such as Chrome or Edge and scrollbar-width: none; is used for Gecko-based browsers, such as Firefox.

I don’t understand this: And because you set overflow: hidden; on your body, you're unable to scroll at all.

As mention in the mdn web docs: "There are no scroll bars, and the clipped content is not visible (i.e., clipped content is hidden), but the content still exists. User agents do not add scroll bars and also do not allow users to view the content outside the clipped region by actions such as dragging on a touch screen or using the scroll wheel on a mouse."
